# Android: Correct way to return a result from a background thread to various activites

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent

I have two activities, ActivityA and ActivityB. ActivityA starts a long-running process (e.g., retrieving data on the web). At any time, the user may decide to move on to ActivityB. As soon as the long-running process is over, its result should be displayed either within ActivityA or ActivityB, whichever is active at that moment.

To implement this, I create a worker thread in ActivityA, and both ActivityA and ActivityB rely on a `LocalBroadcastManager` to be notified of the end of the long-running process and to fetch its result.

This implementation seems to work, but I wonder whether I am missing some corner cases. Here on SO, I see discussions about `IntentService`, `AsyncTask` and `HandlerThread`, so I fear my approach may be too naive. Am I doing this the correct way? If not, what am I missing?

Here are some code snippets to illustrate my question.

**ActivityA**

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    public static final String BROADCAST_MESSAGE = "spike.workerthread.event.resultReady";
    public static final String RESULT_KEY = "spike.workerthread.result";
    private LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastMgr;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

        localBroadcastMgr = LocalBroadcastManager.
            getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                TextView resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
                resultTextView.setText(intent.getStringExtra(RESULT_KEY));
            }};
        localBroadcastMgr.registerReceiver(receiver,
            new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_MESSAGE));
    }       

    public void startFetchingResultFrom(final ResultProvider provider) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String result = provider.getResult(); // Can take a long time...
                Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_MESSAGE);
                intent.putExtra(RESULT_KEY, result);
                localBroadcastMgr.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    public void startActivityB() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

**ActivityB**

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    private LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastMgr;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

        localBroadcastMgr = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                TextView resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
                resultTextView.setText(intent.getStringExtra(ActivityA.RESULT_KEY));
            }};
        localBroadcastMgr.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ActivityA.BROADCAST_MESSAGE));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider making the Activities implement an interface and have this interface be called when the long running task is finished.

AsyncTask is used mostly when you want to perform a long running task and then easily update the UI.

IntentService is a Service that runs on its own Thread and it is terminated when the given task you are performing is finished.

Comment: Having the Activities implement a common interface would be an alternative to using the LocalBroadcastManager. But how would the long running task get a reference to ActivityB's instance?

Comment: I already know about AsyncTask and IntentService. What I am trying to understand is whether there is any downside to using a simple Thread instead of these heavy weight classes.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to think about a setup, which has one model for the Thread f.e. a Service or an Activity based on Fragments. Because if you have your Thread in Activity A and you move on to B than you will loose control over the Thread. And you should avoid this scenario.

As I said have a model and some views, which can access it and control your Thread at any time.

Comment: Could you explain what kind of bad things can happen when my application looses control over the Thread by moving from Activity A to Activity B?